# Best way to return a HTTP Status Code 201 in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, rest, http-status-codes

I'm writing a REST Service in vb.net that I want to allow creation of items and I was wondering which is the best way of returning the 201 Status Code (or 403 if it fails) to the client?

My example code would be:

```
<WebInvoke(method:="POST", UriTemplate:="create/{var}", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml)>            
Public Function CreateTest(ByVal Var As String) As Boolean

    Dim Result As Boolean = True

    'do my processing here and then...
    Throw New WebFaultException(Net.HttpStatusCode.Created) 

    Return Result

End Function
```

So is `Throw New WebFaultException(Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)` the correct way to do this?